# Always picking the default printer instead of the one specified, JAVA

Tags: java, printing

i have a printing program in java, but for some reason it always picks the default printer (8600), even when i pass a value of say xps for printer, what have i done wrong, and how can i get it to select the required printer

heres my code :

```
 PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        System.out.println("Number of print services: " + printServices.length); //tells me how many print services are isntalled on the server.

        for (PrintService printer2 : printServices) {
            System.out.println("Printer: " + printer2.getName()); //prints out the names of all printers on the server, testing purposes 
        } 


        PrintUtility.findPrintService(printer); // selects only the 8600 printer // EDIT now selects any printer with the name provided


        PrintService[] services =
                PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(psInFormat, null);
        //System.out.println("Printers avialiable are " + services);
        System.out.println("Printer Selected " + services[Printerinx]);

        //PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        DocFlavor[] docFalvor = services[Printerinx].getSupportedDocFlavors();
        for (int i = 0; i < docFalvor.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(docFalvor[i].getMimeType());
        }
        if (services.length > 0) {
            DocPrintJob job = services[Printerinx].createPrintJob();
            try {
                job.print(myDoc, aset);
                System.out.print("Printing Doc");
            } catch (PrintException pe) {
                System.out.print(pe);
            }
        }
```

This is the console :

```
INFO: Number of print services: 7
INFO: Printer: Send To OneNote 2013
INFO: Printer: Microsoft XPS Document Writer
INFO: Printer: HP988FD1 (HP Officejet Pro 8600)
INFO: Printer: HP Officejet Pro 8600 (Network)
INFO: Printer: Fax - HP Officejet Pro 8600 (Network)
INFO: Printer: Fax
INFO: Printer: Adobe PDF
INFO: Printer Selected Win32 Printer : HP Officejet Pro 8600 (Network)
INFO: image/gif
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok solved, the printerinx, i have selects which printer can be used, 0 for the first etc, i had set this up to printinx = "3" so it was always selecting the 4th printer, this has been removed and each printer given the right printinx and now its working as it should